# Git pull doesn't abide by .gitignore

Tags: git

I'm a little confused by doing a pull to a server whereby I have a .gitignore that is set to ignore the user generated files. Basically I'm developing and pushing to github, and then deploying with a pull, but I keep deleting my user generated content.

.gitignore looks like this:

```
audio/*/*/*.mp3
audio/*/*/*.wav
audio/*/*/*.ogg

videos/*/*/*.mp4
videos/*/*/*.mov
videos/*/*/*.mpeg

images/*/*/*.jpg
images/*/*/*.jpeg
images/*/*/*.png
images/*/*/*.gif
images/*/*/*.bmp

images/*/*/*/*.jpg
images/*/*/*/*.jpeg
images/*/*/*/*.png
images/*/*/*/*.gif
images/*/*/*/*.bmp
```

I'm not especially knowledgeable with git, so I know I'm doing something wrong.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

.gitignore is for ignoring files when you are trying to *commit* files. It does not look at that when you pull from the repository.

Comment: Is there an appropriate way to pull down a new codebase without affecting user-generated content?

Comment: Consider not having UGC in git?

Comment: Aaaaaarrrrrrrrrrgggghhhhhh.

Answer (score 0):

I am not observing the clobbering behavior you speak of:

Environment 1:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /*****/test/.git/
$ cat > .gitignore <<'EOF'
> audio/*/*/*.mp3
> audio/*/*/*.wav
> audio/*/*/*.ogg
> 
> videos/*/*/*.mp4
> videos/*/*/*.mov
> videos/*/*/*.mpeg
> 
> images/*/*/*.jpg
> images/*/*/*.jpeg
> images/*/*/*.png
> images/*/*/*.gif
> images/*/*/*.bmp
> 
> images/*/*/*/*.jpg
> images/*/*/*/*.jpeg
> images/*/*/*/*.png
> images/*/*/*/*.gif
> images/*/*/*/*.bmp
> EOF
$ touch test.txt
$ mkdir -p audio/one/two/
$ touch audio/one/two/three.mp3
$ touch audio/one/two/three.txt
$ git add -A :/
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
 3 files changed, 19 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 audio/one/two/three.txt
 create mode 100644 test.txt
$ git remote add origin https://***********@bitbucket.org/***********/testrepo.git
$ git push -u origin --all
```

Environment 2:

```
$ git clone https://***********@bitbucket.org/***********/testrepo.git
$ cd testrepo
$ touch test2.txt 
$ git add -A :/
$ git commit -m "Commit two."
$ git push
```

Environment 1:

```
$ touch audio/one/two/three.wav
$ git pull
$ ls -l audio/one/two/
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 ***********  staff  0 Sep 25 11:37 three.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 ***********  staff  0 Sep 25 11:37 three.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ***********  staff  0 Sep 25 11:57 three.wav
```

The files are still there.

Comment: Is this because it was skipped on the push?